# Mysqli num row returned is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm wondering why it is not working for mysqli eventhou mysql_num_row is working.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($rows) > 0) {
    echo "<p>That name has been taken </p>";
}
```

That is mysql. But, Im trying convert it to mysqli.

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($rows) > 0) {
        echo "<p>That name has been taken </p>";
    }
```

It supposed to be displayed on the screen but it's not. And there is nothing error message displayed. Or am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: are you using `mysqli` entirely? If you are running query using `mysql_query` and trying to fetch num_rows using `mysqli_num_rows`, then it will not work. You have to use mysqli functions everywhere.

Comment: in your page you can use  `mysql` or `mysqli` at a time. you cannot use both of them together.

Comment: What is $rows? Show the entire snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a quick tutorial on some of the differences between `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

In `mysql_*` you would have 3 parameters for your DB connection, then have a seperate line for your DB selection.

For example:

```
$db = mysql_connect("host","username", "password");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $db);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use this : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Your query would come first, followed by your DB connection.

For example:

```
mysql_query($query,$db);
```

But in `mysqli_*` things have changed including the parameters location. You now put all 4 parameters, for example (if you haven't done so yet):

```
$db = new mysqli("host","username", "password", "db_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
```

then the DB connection would come first, followed by the query instead of the other way around:

```
mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

A sample query:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email='".$email."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    echo "email already exists";
}else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name (email) VALUES ('$email')";
    if (!mysqli_query($db,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$query = "SELECT name FROM table";

$statement= mysqli_prepare($connect, $query)
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);

if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement) > 0) {
    echo "<p>That name has been taken </p>";
}   

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($connect);
```